# Get last few rows in ascending order in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

What is the best way (Laravel way) to get last few rows of a database table in ascending order? I want the result to be an array of objects as like:

```
[{"name1":"value1"}, {"name2":"value2"}]
```

My recent code is like:

> ```
> $users = User::take(2)->latest()->get()->reverse();
> return $users;
> ```

Output looks like:

```
{"1":{"id":582, "name":"name1"}, "0":{"id":583, "name":"name2"}}
```

But I want the output to be like:

```
[{"id":582, "name":"name1"}, {"id":583, "name":"name2"}]
```

Comment: Try `return $users->values();`; `reverse()` modifies the array but doesn't reassigns indices, `values()` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `reverse()` method, it modifies the `Collection`, but doesn't re-index it, meaning the `Collection` is now `[1, 0]`. JS/JSON treats this as an Object instead of an array, hence the difference:

```
{"1":{"id":582, "name":"name1"}, "0":{"id":583, "name":"name2"}}
// VS
[{"id":582, "name":"name1"}, {"id":583, "name":"name2"}]
```

To solve this, use the `values()` method to re-index the array before return:

```
$users = User::take(2)->latest()->get()->reverse();
return $users->values();
// [{"id":582, "name":"name1"}, {"id":583, "name":"name2"}]
```

If you want them in the other order, don't use `reverse()`, and you shouldn't need `values()` either:

```
$users = User::take(2)->latest()->get();
return $users;
// [{"id":583, "name":"name2"}, {"id":582, "name":"name1"}]
```